# Get How Python Class or Function was Imported

Tags: python, python-module

How can I figure out how a Class or Function was imported in python? I know that `__module__` exists, but that doesn't always work. An example where `__module__` fails:

```
>>> from os.path import join
>>> join.__module__
'ntpath'
```

In that example, I would want to get `os.path` instead. `ntpath` is where the function was defined, not the package from which I imported the function.

**Edit**:

Specifically, the reason I'd like to get `os.path` instead of `ntpath` is because `os.path` is platform independent whereas `ntpath` only exists on Windows. Similarly, on *nix systems, `os.path` is implemented using `posixpath`. If nobody can give me a reliable way of solving this problem, I guess an acceptable substitute would be some kind of map I could use that maps from implementation modules back to cross platform modules. IE, to start it off it would look like this:

```
{
 'nt'       : 'os',
 'ntpath'   : 'os.path',
 'posixpath': 'os.path',

}
```

I only need the modules that are part of a standard Python install (specifically 2.7).

**Second Edit**:

I want to make it possible to write something like this:

```
from pyRemote import Remote  # The module I'm writing
from os.path  import join

remote = Remote(hostname, username, password)
pathOnRemoteMachine = remote.join(component1, component2)
```

To make this work, `Remote` implements `__getattr__` by looking up the attribute name in the calling namespace (using some methods from `inspect`.) It finds that in the calling namespace `join` is a function. It needs to know where `join` can be imported from, so that it can tell the remote Python instance to import that same function. Since the local Python instance could be running on a different OS from the remote Python instance (IE, local could be Windows while remote could be RedHat), I don't want the implementation specific module (`ntpath` in this case) - I want the cross platform module (`os.path` in this case).

I'll also handle the scenario of needing to import from a module that came from pip by telling the remote machine to download it from pip first, or the scenario of needing to import from a file written by the user by copying that file over.

So it's a huge pile of magic and hacks to provide a very elegant (IMO) way of controlling a remote Python instance using a local Python instance.

Comment: This problem is intractable.

Comment: in your example, `ntpath` is the module it is imported from.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Why do you care that you get the platform independent result, on *nix you would get posixpath and windows you would get ntpath, still seems portable. Echo above, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist: I want to take a line of code which is valid on the local machine and run it on a remote instance of python, which may or may not have the same OS.

Comment: And that bit of code doesn't include the import statement itself?

Comment: @achampion: Made a second edit to elaborate more exactly on what I want to do and why and how I want to do it.

Comment: Looks interesting, you could just make it a requirement to introduce the functions into the remote namespace, perhaps as separate calls to remote.include() or on initialisation of remote object. There are other packages that have OS specific implementations, will be difficult to catch them all.

Comment: @achampion: Start of something promising: `for attr, value in os.__dict__.iteritems(): print(value.__module__)` - prints out a lot of `nt` on Windows. So that tells me that `nt` maps to `OS`. I can run similar code that loops over all modules to look for this kind of thing. Run it once on Windows, once on Unix, and once on OS X for good measure and I'll have a list of all the OS specific implementation modules.

Answer (score 2):

You can index into the `sys.modules`, e.g.

```
>>> import sys
>>> from os.path import join
>>> sys.modules[join.__module__]
"<path/posixpath.pyc>"
```

However, this will only give you the actual module, not the name you reference, e.g. (os.path). Not sure how you can possibly tell how the function is imported, just where it is defined.

Comment: Neat, but that reveals the exact problem. I want to get `os.path` because that is platform independent. `ntpath` is how `os.path` is implemented on Windows and `posixpath` is how `os.path` is implemented on *nix systems.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if this is possible because os.path is not retained.

Comment: See my edit for a possible alternative answer approach.

Comment: It does sound very similar, and I wish I had known that existed earlier so that I wouldn't have bothered going down the road I did. But at this point, I feel like it'd be easier to just finish what I started than to learn a different library.